# Given an integer array nums, return true if any value appears at least twice in the array, and return false if every element is distinct

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static boolean repeat(int[] arr){

    for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j= i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
           if(arr[i] == arr[j]) {
            return true;
           }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static boolean repeat(int[] arr){
   for(int i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
       
           if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
            return true;
           }
        
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

The Above code returns true and bottom code returns true? Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: The bottom code only returns true if your input has the same number twice in a row. Try it with 1, 2, 3, 2, and see what it returns.

Comment: Use a set, and iterate adding the numbers. Use a condition for checking if the set contains the number if so stop the loop and return otherwise kerp looping. Or transform the array to set and check if the size is different.

Comment: If you want to salvage the bottom code, you could sort the array first.